# How to properly fork+exec in ncurses?

Tags: c, fork, exec, ncurses

I've looked around, but there doesn't seem to be anything on using fork+exec with ncurses.
Here's my attempt at a simple program:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

extern char **environ;

int
main(void){
  initscr(); cbreak(); noecho();
  pid_t child;

  mvprintw(0, 0, "press to continue"), refresh();
  getch();

  if (!(child = fork())) {
    def_prog_mode(), endwin();
    if (execve("/bin/ksh", (char*[]){"ksh", NULL}, environ) < 0) {
      perror("execve failed");
    }
  }
  else if (child > 0) {
    wait(&child);
    reset_prog_mode(), refresh();
    mvprintw(0, 0, "Done!"), refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
  }
  else {
    endwin();
    perror("fork failed");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

It works fine, except output by the `execve`-ed process is all below the shell prompt that I get once the program is finished. [Video to understand what I mean.](https://asciinema.org/a/WNVpITCUGKYrL8qz4HBt8NYum)

What is the proper way to fork+exec without mangled output?

Comment: It looks correct to me. When you call `endwin()` it returns the cursor to where it was when you did `initscr()` (if I remember correctly). Since you do that in the child process, that's where it'll be to take the user input. After the child is dead, you do it again in the parent process so it'll return to the same place again.

Comment: That's... exactly why I'm asking. But now that you say `endwin()` returns the cursor to where it was when `initscr()` was called, what happens makes sense: I started at the top left, started another process whose output went to around the middle, and then I returned to the top left when I'm done. The question is how do I return the cursor to where it finished in the child process now...

Comment: Hmm, as far as I recall, that's tricky with curses. You could perhaps query the terminfo database and send the necessary escape sequences instead of using `initscr()`/`endwin()`, much like the `tput` command line utility does. Perhaps you can look at the source code for `tput` to get an idea of what can be done.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with terminfo and `tput`; pointers for resources on them would be very appreciated. But surely it can't be *that* tricky: I can't name anything specific off the top of my head, but iirc stuff like RetroPie-setup and other community rpi utilities definitely switch between `curses` and cooked mode to show output of commands... ofc the easy way out is to clear the screen before exiting the program; but that's no fun, is it?

Comment: [Here are some links](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22tput.c%22+terminfo) where you can read about terminfo and also study the source code of `tput.c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out if I move `def_prog_mode(), refresh()` out of the child process and into the parent process, everything works fine. Makes sense: two process controlling the same `curses` window doesn't seem like something that'd work.

Here's the fixed code:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

extern char **environ;

int
main(void){
  initscr(); cbreak(); noecho();
  pid_t child;

  mvprintw(0, 0, "press to continue"), refresh();
  getch();

  def_prog_mode(), endwin();
  if (!(child = fork())) {
    if (execve("/bin/ksh", (char*[]){"ksh", NULL}, environ) < 0) {
      perror("execve failed");
    }
  }
  else if (child > 0) {
    wait(&child);
    reset_prog_mode(), erase();
    mvprintw(0, 0, "Done!"), refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
  }
  else {
    endwin();
    perror("fork failed");
  }

  return 0;
}
```